# How can I loop over objects each object after a specific time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class CompareObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float waitTime;

    private GameObject[] allObjects;

    public void Compare()
    {
        allObjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();

        foreach (GameObject go in allObjects)
        {
            Debug.Log(go.name + " >>>>> " + go.scene.name + " >>>>> is active object");
            StartCoroutine(Comparing());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Comparing()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    }
}
```

The idea is not to choke the whole editor and wait for the `foreach` loop to finish, but to make that it will loop over the first item wait a second then will continue to the next and so on.

The way it is now it's choking the editor, freezing it until the loop is over.

What I did so far and it's not working good yet :

I created a new editor script for a button in the inspector :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(CompareObjects))]
public class CompareObjectsButton : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        CompareObjects myTarget = (CompareObjects)target;

        if (GUILayout.Button("Compare Objects"))
        {
            myTarget.StartComparing();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in Compare Objects :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class CompareObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float waitTime;

    private Coroutine comparer;
    private GameObject[] allObjects;

    public void StartComparing()
    {
        if (comparer == null)
        {
            comparer = StartCoroutine(Compare());
        }
    }

    public void StopComparing()
    {
        if (comparer != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(comparer);

            comparer = null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Compare()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            allObjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();

            foreach (GameObject go in allObjects)
            {
                Debug.Log(go.name + " >>>>> " + go.scene.name + " >>>>> is active object");

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it's doing only one object and not all the objects.

Comment: The code you have posted should work for listing all the game objects, not sure why you are only seeing one.  Also, if you are getting frame drops with this code it is probably because of this line `allObjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();` not the prints.  the function FindObjectsOfType is pretty slow(and by that I mean very slow) and it might even be faster to just parse your hierarchy.  Something else to consider is if you could restructure your GOs to be children of a parent, utilize layers, or tags to compare against less objects.  Also, you might want to look at the jobs system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StartCoroutine kind of acts in the same manner as starting a new thread, so when you call `Compare` all you are doing is looping through the game objects and creating event objects which, while running in the main thread, don't prevent the method which created it from running, so ultimately only the new event object waits the specified time while the main method continues to loop through the rest of the game objects and creating more event objects, sins it itself isn't calling any sleep functions, instead you should do something like this:

```
public void StartComparing()
{
    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = StartCoroutine(Compare());
    }
}

public void StopComparing()
{
    if (comparer != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(comparer);

        comparer = null;
    }
}

IEnumerator Compare()
{
    while (true)
    {
        allObjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();

        foreach (GameObject go in allObjects)
        {
            Debug.Log(go.name + " >>>>> " + go.scene.name + " >>>>> is active object");

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        }
    }
}

private Coroutine comparer;

private GameObject[] allObjects;

public float waitTime;
```

`StartComparing` will start a coroutine of `Compare` which will go through all the objects, so, first object then wait the specified `waitTime` then the second object and so on, this is done until `StopComparing` is called.

Tested the code, here is a small (literally) preview of it, you will see that after changing the speed it logs the objects slower:

[image]

Comment: I tried but it's looping only over one object and stop. I will edit my question with what I did.

Comment: @DanielLip how many objects do you get after calling `FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>()`, and what do you set the `waitTime` field to, because it doesn't look like it's being set to anything?

Comment: And also when changing the waitTime it's not doing anything it's still doing only one object and very fast.

Comment: @DanielLip give me a minute, I will try to recreate what you are doing and tell you my results.

Comment: I'm getting over 10000 objects in FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>() but yet it's doing only one object.

Comment: Np, Thank you. I'm waiting.

Comment: @DanielLip The code works just fine for me, I can change the speed at which each object is compared and it goes through all of the, not just one. Will make a gif and put it in the answer so you can see.

Comment: `StartCoroutine basically creates a new thread` That's technically **wrong**! Coroutines run in the main thread and are more like an additional temporary `Update` method .. it has nothing to do with threads! If it really were threads you couldn't even use things like `FindObjectOfType` or `Debug.Log` as they are only allowed in the main thread ;)

Comment: @derHugo is correct.  StartCoroutine is more like a time share implementation of parallelism using callbacks than proper async.  They do indeed run in the main thread, and they get batched to be executed later on in the game loop, see: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: Ah yes, that s true, what I mean by that statement was that coroutines kind of act like threads, will change it.

Comment: Oops sorry my bad. It's working I forgot that I have to run the game. For some reason I was sure that using [ExecuteInEditMode] can make it work also without running the game. I don't need it in the game I need it in the editor for comparing objects.  So it's working fine just not like I wanted or thought. Is there a way to make it working also in edit mode without running the game ?

Comment: @DanielLip AFAIK no, there is no way of making it work without playing the scene.